# How to keep UITextView editable in UITableViewCell on scrolling and keep its dynamic size?

Tags: swift, uitableview, uitextview

I have an editable UITextView in UITableViewCell. When I paste some big text, update the cell size (and even keep the new size in a cache), then scroll out, so the tableView should deallocate the cell, then return back — the cell is not editable anymore (but the keyboard still active), and the size doesn't match the size of the textView. However, the textView has the right text, and if I end the editing and preserve the data, everything works. How can I keep the cell editable and maintain the size? Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide your code implementation? For every reload of the cell is there logic that enables making the cell editable or not? Perhaps setting the cell to disabled is being triggered on reuse.

Comment: You were right, the problem was in the cleaning function on prepareForReuse. Thank you!

Comment: Cool, kindly accept this as an answer to be closed :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you provide your code implementation? For every reload of the cell is there logic that enables making the cell editable or not? Perhaps setting the cell to disabled is being triggered on reuse.